# PHP 7.4 with last version of sqlite3

Tags: php, sqlite

CentOS8 is distributed with sqlite3 version 3.26.
I would like to build a php 7.4 RPM with the version 3.35 of sqlite3.
Do you any advice to do so ?

Comment: Why do you think you need version 3.35 ? Fedora don't even have it yet, only in Fedora rawhide (35). This version was released only 2 weeks ago...

Comment: I just want to have a method to do so

Answer (score 0):

Use Fedora instead of CentOS, and its packages of php and sqlite. Perhaps confined to VMs or containers for applications requiring such a stack. RHEL is not going to be upgrading versions any time soon, and few packagers are interested in breaking something by replacing sqlite in particular.

Fedora moves fast however, expect [PHP 8 for Fedora 35](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/php80). This is actually slower than typical as [PHP 8 was deferred for Fedora 34](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=PHP-8.0-For-Fedora-35). Use the few months remaining (as of now April 2021) in Fedora's support of php 7.4 to migrate to 8, or devise some other plan.

While possible to build your own packages, this is more work than installing a distro that already has them. Review the rpm changelog and [Remi's PHP blog](https://blog.remirepo.net/) to get some appreciation for the ongoing maintenance work that you would be responsible for.